# Flutter setState not updating the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm react developer trying out with flutter.

I have stateful widget as following

```dart
// progress_indicators: ^0.1.2
import 'package:progress_indicators/progress_indicators.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  var _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() { _isLoading = false; });
  }

  @overide 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Form(),
          _isLoading ? JumpingDotsProgressIndicator(
              fontSize: 60.0,
           ): Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0))
        ]
      )
    )
  }

  onLogin() async {
    final response = await loginUser(_userController.text.trim(), _passController.text.trim());
    setState(() { _isLoading = true; });
    if(response == true) {
      print("User Logging take them to activity");
    } else {
      setState(() { _isLoading = false; });
      bottomModel(response['message']);
    }
  }
}
```

`JumpingDotsProgressIndicator` is a method from `progress_indicators` which provides me a simple loader.

I want to show the loader while my `loginUser` method is happening. `loginUser` is a simple post req to the my NodeJS server.

Also `onLogin` is called when button is clicked that lives in the `Form()`.
Everything is working fine but the loader is not displaying even though I'm setting the state.

What am I doing wrong with the conditional rendering ?

I had one more ques

```dart
_isLoading ? JumpingDotsProgressIndicator(
  fontSize: 60.0,
): Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0))
```

here I'm giving `0` padding which is like a null widget so I also tried adding `null` in place of `Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0))` then in the emulator it was showing `Assertion failed`.

Can someone explain me the reason for that as well ?

Thanks in adv!

Comment: I do not get where you are calling the onLogin() function. It it is a button where you call onLogin() on onPressed try to add the setState() also to this oppressed, instead of into the onLogin() function

Comment: to your second question: you can not add null as a widget. I usually use an empty container like Container()

Comment: @Neli inside the form i have a button on which i have `onPressed: onLogin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi try to remove `setState(() { _isLoading = false; });` from `initState()` otherwise everytime the widget builds new because state was changed it will set _isLoading to false before you can even see the expected behaviour. In a nutshell with your code your state could never be true.